# Excel - Drop down list containing dynamic content from first column based on value in a second column

Tags: excel

I have two columns one with a list of names and a second with a Yes/No indicating if they are available. This second column is manually updated

I would like to add a drop down list at another location that only shows the names for which the availability is set to yes.

Can this be done in any version of Excel?

I know there can be issues if a name is picked but later the availability is changed to 'No'. In this case the ideal scenario would be the cell changes colour

Comment: Kindly refer this link http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html

Comment: Thanks for that. This requires a list to be sorted. As the data can change, then this would mean resorting each time for the drop down to update. Can this be avoided?

Comment: Try to split the list of names in 2 lists, 1 with Yes and 1 with No. Then apply a dynamic named range depending on the selection for Yes or No.

Comment: so is there a way to create a dynamic table that can be refreshed but gives a filtered set based on the availability criteria? The next step from this would be to name the range in that table and use in list

Answer (score 1):

i think this  may help you...

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/